# How RxJava avoid deadlock and how it never runs out of I/O threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, deadlock, java-threads

How RxJava avoid deadlock and how it never runs out of I/O threads?
I understood that Rxjava has a limited pool of i/o threads. Why it never runs out of I/O threads?

How RxJava avoid deadlock and how it never runs out of I/O threads?

Comment: The IO scheduler spawns as many threads as needed, up to the OS limit of a few thousand. To avoid deadlock, don't block.

Comment: But in case where there are more request than the máximum number of rhreads and Considering that there is no messaging queue like Kafka, only direct HTTP requests. In this case what happens to the request ?

Comment: There is a crash and any subsequent request will most likely timeout on the client. Running on an unbounded pool in a server environment is not a good idea. Create a bounded pool and share it via `Schedulers.from`.

Comment: @akarnokd Thanks for your answaer! i'd like to mark your comment as a correct answer, plz post this as an answer instead of a comment